# Using a cell phone to make calls without signing into Google account. Possible?

Tags: calls, google-account

I intend to close my Google account for personal reasons.  No part of it will I leave operable.

But, I use an Android phone.  I am not asking about Google apps here.  I am asking if the phone will still work for making phone calls.  Mind you if I have it my way there will be no Google account for me to login to.

I am dumping Google in it's entirety.

Comment: Edited to match the heading with body. Trust that's fine by you

Comment: afaik every device is running fine without google account, it isn't requirement. non-google apps are working too, just google play store is not available for install. but *"dumping Google in it's entirety"* is impossible

Comment: @alecxs It depends on your definition of *"dumping Google in it's entirety"* to state whether or not it's possible.  If one's definition is not connecting to any Google servers, then it is certainly possible (and easy).  If the definition is not using any Google services, then it is trivially simple.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket google services is core for android os, i don't agree it is trivial (and i doubt it is even possible) but a good start to play with is app [cn.wq.disableservice](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225549) and [microG](https://github.com/microg/GmsCore/wiki)

Comment: @alecxs You can block Google servers (and all Google-assigned IP ranges, for that matter) with a firewall - on the device, on the access point, or at the network level.  Additionally, you can block DNS resolution for all Google hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it *only* to make and receive calls and text messages. Equivalent of not signing into a new device but inserting SIM.

I have seen people do this (without signing into Google account) , using it like a non-smartphone.

Somewhat related [Can I use an Android One device without a Google account? Isn't there a compulsion?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224520/131553)

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used Android phones without any Google account, or even connecting them to the internet.

Many key features will still work:

- Telephone calls
- Voicemail (call to retrieve messages)
- SMS messages
- Still camera
- Video camera
- Audio recording (if there is a pre-installed audio recording app)
- Creating contacts
- Calendar (including creating events)
- Alarm clock
- Flashlight
- Bluetooth connections (speakers, headphones, etc.)

In fact, without Google slowing down Android, it is a much faster and efficient operating system.